# validation tools in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

i have a registration form in asp.net
i want to make a failed to user comments it is a multiline textbox and i want to let the use write only 100 character in this box and if he enter more.. i want to  only accept the first 100 character  and delete the other then send the user error massage with the accepted part of text
i have tried to use RegularExpressionValidator like this:

```html
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Comment should be less the 100 letter." ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^.{1,100}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but i still want yo show the user the accepted part and to delete the rest from the box
so how could i do this using validation tools

Answer (score 1):

just add two lines on your `Page_Load` event

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Remove("MaxLength");
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("MaxLength", "100");
```

this will make it work even if you set `TextBox` to `MultiLine` mode.

With javascript you can do like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function LimtCharacters(txtMsg, CharLength, indicator) {
            chars = txtMsg.value.length;
            document.getElementById(indicator).innerHTML = CharLength - chars;
            if (chars > CharLength) {
                txtMsg.value = txtMsg.value.substring(0, CharLength);
            }
        }
</script>
```

write this on your aspx page

```
Number of Characters Left:

<label id="lblcount" style="background-color:#E2EEF1;color:Red;font-weight:bold;">100</label><br/>

<asp:TextBox ID="multiTxtBox"  TextMode="MultiLine" onkeyup="LimtCharacters(this,100,'lblcount');" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: I never thought of that! Would the second line on its own override/obviate the first?

Comment: that's good but i need to tell the user that his text is tall and show the accepted text